# Having a syntax error while trying to create a random number generating game

Tags: python, syntax

I cannot figure out why I'm having this syntax error. It says number is not defined but 'number' is set to 'raw_input'. Can anyone help me out? Here's the code and error message-

```
def main():

number = raw_input('I have a number between 1 and 10. Can you guess it? Please type your first guess: ')

guess(number)


def guess(number):
    randomNumber = random.randrange(1,10)


 correct = False

while not correct:

if number > randomNumber:
        print'Too High. Try again.'
    elif number < randomNumber:
        print'Too Low. Try again.'
    elif number == randomNumber:
        print'Correct!'

playAgain = raw_input('Excellent! You guessed the number! Would you like to play again (y or n)? ')
        if playAgain == 'y':
            main()



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#48>", line 2, in <module>
    if number > randomNumber:
NameError: name 'number' is not defined
```

Comment: It's Python, but I'm going to leave it up to the OP to fix all the obviously wrong indentation. Or maybe the obviously wrong indentation is part of the problem; I can't tell.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you're getting the current error, as I encounter a different syntax error when attempting to run your code. That being said, there are many things causing problems here, not just the assignment of `number`.

In Python, indentation controls how the statements in your code are executed. Things like `def` and `if` must have their body indented, otherwise you cause either syntax or logic errors.

[This page words it better than I do.](http://www.python-course.eu/blocks.php)

In your current program:

- `def main():` is empty
- `number = raw_input( ...` is outside of the `main()` method
- `guess(number)` is also outside the `main()` method
- Most of `guess()` is outside of the function body
- `correct = False` does not match any other indentation level

Additionally, even when the indentation is fixed, your current code doesn't ask the user for input more than once, and it won't maintain the same target number over multiple `guess()` calls. The `main()` method is also not called.

Try this:

```python
import random

def main():

    guess()


def guess():

    number = int(raw_input('I have a number between 1 and 10. Can you guess it? Please type your first guess: '))
    randomNumber = random.randrange(1,10)

    while true:

        if number > randomNumber:
            print 'Too High. Try again.'
        elif number < randomNumber:
            print 'Too Low. Try again.'
        elif number == randomNumber:
            print 'Correct!'
            break

        number = int(raw_input('I have a number between 1 and 10. Can you guess it? Please type next guess: '))

    playAgain = raw_input('Excellent! You guessed the number! Would you like to play again (y or n)? ')

    if playAgain == 'y':

        main()


main()
```

Comment: Please also add a comment about how this addresses the OP's question. While obvious to me, the OP might just pop this in place and not learn about how indentation matters in Python.